# Handle circular import of subclasses types in abstract class

Tags: python, python-3.x, coding-style, python-typing, typing

I am facing a circular import error when I define type aliases for the subclasses of an abstract class.

This is an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```py
#abstract_file_builder.py

from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import Generic, MutableSequence, TypeVar

from mymodule.type_a_file_builder import TypeARow
from mymodule.type_b_file_builder import TypeBRow

GenericRow = TypeVar("GenericRow", TypeARow, TypeBRow)

class AbstractFileBuilder(ABC, Generic[GenericRow]):
    ...
    
    @abstractmethod
    def generate_rows(
        self,
    ) -> MutableSequence[GenericRow]:
        pass
```

```py
#type_a_file_builder.py

from typing import Any, MutableSequence

from mymodule.abstract_file_builder import AbstractFileBuilder

TypeARow = MutableSequence[Any]

class TypeAFileBuilder(AbstractFileBuilder[TypeARow]):
    ...

    def generate_rows(
        self,
    ) -> MutableSequence[TypeARow]:
        ... # Code logic for TypeA
        return rows
```

```py
#type_b_file_builder.py

from typing import MutableSequence, Union

from mymodule.abstract_file_builder import AbstractFileBuilder

TypeBRow = MutableSequence[Union[int, float]]

class TypeBFileBuilder(AbstractFileBuilder[TypeBRow]):
    ...

    def generate_rows(
        self,
    ) -> MutableSequence[TypeBRow]:
        ... # Code logic for TypeB
        return rows
```

What is the most pythonic way to solve this?

I know I can use the `TYPE_CHECKING` variable to avoid runtime imports, but that feels like a patch instead of a good solution.

Another thing that can solve the problem is to define the type aliases in the abstract class, but that would ruin the whole purpose of having an abstract class and not having to know what's implemented below.

I'm not sure however if I can do some form of an "abstract" type alias inside the `abstract_file_builder.py` file, and then declare the TypeARow and TypeBRow types as children of that abstract type.

I must note that the solution must work with, at least, `Python 3.9`. If it supports versions back to `3.7` it'll be better, but not super necessary.

Comment: Hi Carlos, thank you for accepting my answer. Btw. what was the original idea of specifying `Generic[GenericRow]` in `class AbstractFileBuilder(ABC, Generic[GenericRow])`. You do not seem to inheriting any behavior of the TypeRow-casses, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By placing the following line in your abstract class you kind of add information of your concrete subclasses to your abstract class:

```
GenericRow = TypeVar("GenericRow", TypeARow, TypeBRow)
```

That doesn't look right to me. I think you should rather remove this dependency, because in consequence it would mean, that you potentially would have to change the definiton of the return type of your abstract method again in case you add another subclass later. I would only consider this in case you think your subclasses are pretty fixed and neither the return type changes nor new subclasses are added.

In that case, you could just put the three classes in one file and put the definitions of the return types before the definition of your abstract class.

But because we usually do not know if we add other subclasses later (why would we care about creating abstract superclasses otherwise), I think the superclass should not have knowledge about the subclasses.

In that case I would rather type the abstract method with the broader type, e.g. like this:

```
#abstract_file_builder.py

from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import Generic, MutableSequence, TypeVar

class AbstractFileBuilder(ABC):
    ...
    
    @abstractmethod
    def generate_rows(
        self,
    ) -> MutableSequence[Any]:
        pass
```

Comment: I think you made a mistake while editing my code, as you left the `GenericRow` class there. Anyway, I agree with the fact that I don't want the abstract class to know anything about the subclasses. However, I feel like using `Any` is a very broad approach, isn't it? Isn't there any way to create a "generic" type alias in the abstract class and then in the subclasses "inherit" that type when creating the aliases for each subclass?

Comment: Hola Carlos. I didn't recognize that. Thanks for pointing this out. But why do you want to add a generic subperclass at all? what do you want to inherit from it? I would remove that as well, so that you have a clean subclass that has no knowledge about it's subclasses.
Yes `Any` is quite broad, but one of your subclasses even uses this concretely, so how could you be any more precise?
Besides if you define:
```GenericRow = TypeVar("GenericRow", TypeARow, TypeBRow)
GenericRow = TypeVar("GenericRow", MutableSequence[Any], MutableSequence[Union[int, float]])
```

Comment: ...then I think GenericRow will not be any narrower than if you just do `TypeVar("GenericRow", MutableSequence[Any])`, because this is the superset of `MutableSequence[Union[int, float]])` anyways, right?

Comment: Yes, I think you're indeed right. I was a bit adamant on that, but the fact is that the abstract class may accept anything as element of the MutableSequence. I wasn't sure on using `MutableSequence[Any]` because I was thinking of it having to be `MutableSequence[MutableSequence[X]]]`, but the fact that the two current implementations of rows are MutableSequence doesn't change that in other future subclasses rows can be represented as any other type, as long as `generate_rows` returns a MutableSequence of that type. Accepting the answer :)

Comment: @CarlosMorente in general, you should identify what properties a `GenericRow` must have. I'd strongly recommend against using `Any` instead of whole typevar - it reduces type safety. If you know that `GenericRow` is something with a `foo` method, declare a `typing.Procotol` and use `GenericRow = TypeVar('GenericRow', bound=YourFooableProtocol)` instead. If you don't need any methods/attributes of it, omit bound entirely and just use `TypeVar('GenericRow')`

Comment: For mutable sequence it could be like [this](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=ed8dc0885e7ec225e3d2ce214ec25f29). In more general case where you need some specific attributes - [like this](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.11&flags=strict&gist=9a2690797c712bf9ef7ce887dcd14982) (you may want ABC's instead of protocols, if rows have to implement some common interface and should inherit from some your AbstractBaseRow ABC)